# OnChildViewHolderSelectedListener is called before animation is complete in HorizontalGridView with setSelectedPositionSmooth

Tags: java, android, leanback

I'm using `HorizontalGridView` in `android.support.v17.leanback.widget` package. The problem is that `OnChildViewHolderSelectedListener` is called too early.

```
    horizontalGrid.setSelectedPosition(position);
    horizontalGrid.setOnChildViewHolderSelectedListener(new OnChildViewHolderSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildViewHolderSelected(RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.ViewHolder child, int position, int subposition) {
            super.onChildViewHolderSelected(parent, child, position, subposition);
            //the animation isn't complete
            //horizontalGrid.getLayoutManager().isSmoothScrolling() is true;
        }
    });
```

The only choices that I'm aware of is to use a `TimerTask` with `Timer` and  check if `horizontalGrid.getLayoutManager().isSmoothScrolling()` is false.  Another less reliable solution is to use a `Handler` with `postDelayed` method. Both ways are ugly in my case.
I haven't found any built-in methods. Am I missing something? Is there something more elegant?

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm trying to find the X coordinate of the selected child, but the value is wrong because this callback comes before the animation changes the view's position. I tried with `onChildViewHolderSelectedAndPositioned`, but it didn't help - it is not called all the time and the X coordinate is still wrong anyway.